# byte[] to String {100,25,28,-122,-26,94,-3,-26}

Tags: java, byte

How can I convert this byte[] to String :

```
byte[] mytest = new byte[] {100,25,28,-122,-26,94,-3,-26};
```

i get this : `"d��^�"` when I use :

```
new String( mytest , "UTF-8" )
```

Here is code java for creation of key :

```
m_key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(new byte[] {100,25,28,-122,-26,94,-3,-26}, "DES");
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is desired result?

Comment: I hope this byte array is encrypted value...

Comment: The only bytes in the input that are in the ASCII non-control code range, 100 and 94, were printed correctly.

Comment: I need to know what is mean this word...it's key of Cryption DES ecb in byte. I want to use this key in my Cryption PHP version...and PHP uses key only in String not in byte...

Comment: Are you sure it's not expecting a Base64 encoded string?

Comment: Here is a code java for creation of key :

m_key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec     (new byte[] {100,25,28,-122,-26,94,-3,-26}, "DES");

Comment: If you just want to print the numeric values of the bytes just do `for(byte b : mytest){System.out.print(b + " ");}` If you expect the bytes to have some meaning, then you **need to** specify the way in which they were encoded before you can decode them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to decode the byte array into something like ASCII, you need to know its original encoding. Otherwise you would need to treat it as binary.

Note: Base64 is intended for transferring binary data across networks.

I would suggest Base64 encoding your byte array. Then in your PHP code decoding the Base64 string back into a UTF-8 string.

In Java, here's how to Base64 encode your byte array and then decode it back to UTF-8:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {100,25,28,-122,-26,94,-3,-26};
        System.out.println("To UTF-8 string: " + new String(byteArray, "UTF-8"));

        byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(byteArray);
        System.out.println("To Base64 string: " + new String(base64, "UTF-8"));

        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
        System.out.println("Back to UTF-8 string: " + new String(decoded, "UTF-8"));

        /* the decoded byte array is the same as the original byte array */
        for (int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
            assert byteArray[i] == decoded[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the above code is:

```
To UTF-8 string: d��^�
To Base64 string: ZBkchuZe/eY=
Back to UTF-8 string: d��^�
```

So if you wanted to use the same binary data in your PHP code, cut and paste the Base64 string into your PHP code and decode it back to UTF-8. Something like this:

```
<?php
$str = 'ZBkchuZe/eY=';
$key = base64_decode($str);
echo $key;
?>
```

I don't code in PHP, but you should be able to decode Base64 using this method:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

The above code should echo back the original binary data as UTF-8 (albeit with funny characters). The point is that the funny-looking string in the `$key` variable is representing the same binary data you had in the Java byte array:

```
d��^�
```

You should be able to pass the `$key` variable into your PHP encryption method.

Comment: thank you very much, its working with  : 
  $str = 'ZBkchuZe/eY=';
  $key = base64_decode($str);

Answer (score 0):

with the way you are doing it makes no sense imo. you are creating a new string with the byte[] as an argument. i dont think that function is suppose to parse. so what you end up with is a lot of junk. but a little bit of googling got me this:  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Would m_key.getEncoded() give you the desired result.

Javadocs - [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html)

If not, you have to identify the Key provider that was used for the encoding (which resulted in the byte array that you have now) and decode.